# Tips for function inside while loop and i=i+1, Matlab

Tags: function, matlab, while-loop

I have a problem with a function in matlab. This specific function is for filtering light signals. As you can see below I added the coding I’ve used in the function and in the while loop itself. The code is written for a NXT Lego robot.

Is there any tip how to get the count variable ( i = i + 1 ) to work in the function, so we can plot Light(i)?  Because we’re getting a bunch of error messages when we try different codes to make it work.

```
function  [light]  = filter_func( i)
  lightI(i) = GetLight(SENSOR_3);  

  if i==1
    light(i)=lightI(i)

  elseif i==2
    light(i) =  0.55*lightI(i) + 0.45*lightI(i-1)
  else
    light(i) =  0.4*lightI(i) + 0.3*lightI(i-1) + 0.3*lightI(i-2);
  end

end

i=1
while true
  lightI(i) = GetLight(SENSOR_3); % Get’s a lightvalue between    0 and 1024.
  if i>2
    light =filter_func(i)
    light=round(light); 
  else
    light(i) = GetLight(SENSOR_3);;
  end
  i=1+i  

  plot(light(end-90:end), 'r-');
  title('Lightvalue')
  axis([0 100 0 1023]) ;
end
```

Comment: It would be a lot easier if you formatted the code snippet. It's hard to read. And also say what you expect to happen (beyond `plot(Light(i)`)...

Comment: Your while-loop never ends, so you keep overwriting your plot. This is clearly not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

You probably mainly get errors because you are not allowed to mix script and functions like this in MATLAB (like you are in Python).

Your filter function is only used when i>2 so why are you doing the first 2 tests? It seems like you want lightI as a global variable, but that is not what you have done. The lightI inside the function is not the same as the one in the while loop.

Since your while loop runs forever, maybe you don't need to worry about updating the plot the first two times. In that case you can do this:

```
filter                  = [0.4 0.3 0.3]';
latest_filtered_light   = nan(90,1);
lightI                  = [];
p                       = plot(latest_filtered_light, 'r-');
title('Lightvalue')
axis([0 100 0 1023]) ;

while True
    lightI(end+1,1) = rand*1024; % Get’s a lightvalue between    0 and 1024.
    if i>=3
        new_val               = lightI(end-2:end,1)'*filter;
        latest_filtered_light = [latest_filtered_light(2:end);...
                                new_val];
        set(p, 'ydata', latest_filtered_light)
        drawnow
    end
end
```

I think it is an important point to not call plot every time - at least if you are the least concerned about performance.